# How to work on a specific sheet through a cell value?

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA and I find it rather difficult. I'm encountering what I think to be an easy problem, but I cannot manage to solve it.

I need to get the dates from different years (sheets) when the emission of a pollutant went over a certain limit(4 different limits). So I made a list on a cell which I named _YEAR and another list that I named _SEUIL. But for some reason, my code doesn't understand when I use the value of _YEAR to indicate the specific sheet I want to work on :/

This is my code :

```
Sub Recherche()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Y As String
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Y = CStr("_YEAR")
S = "_SEUIL"                'Entrée du seuil
SD = "_SORTIEDATE"          'Sortie des dates
SV = "_SORTIEVAL"           'Sortie des valeurs
SC = "_SORTIECOM"           'Sortie des commentaires
                            
RD = Range(SD).Row
RV = Range(SV).Row
RC = Range(SC).Row

CD = Range(SD).Column
CV = Range(SV).Column
CC = Range(SC).Column
                             
Set Ws = Worksheets(Y) 'This is the bug on my code

lastRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow Step 1

    If Range(i, 3).Value > S Then
        Range(RD + i, CD).Value = Range(i, 1).Value
        Range(RV + i, CV).Value = Range(i, 3).Value
        Range(RC + i, CC).Value = Range(i, 4).Value
    End If
 
Next

MsgBox ("Execution terminée")

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for the help !

Comment: How many sheets do you have ? Be carefull is SD, SV and SC are on different sheets, if you write ```Range``` with no sheet associated, it will take a ```Range``` on ```ActiveSheet``` instead of another sheet where data might actually be.

Comment: Maybe the worksheet is not named correctly (maybe there are extra spaces in the worksheet name that you're not seeing?  Please check to make the value of `Y` and the worksheet name match exactly.

Comment: I have 16 different sheets and SD,SV and SC are on the same sheet and they represent names cells, so I think I avoided that mistake.

Comment: I verified the name of the sheets everything match !